# Is this a good layout for BQ40Z60-based battery management unit?

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion

Could you please take a look at board layout and tell is there some stupid mistakes.

I tried to accomplish the following characteristics:

- Max discharge current: 10A
- Max charge current: 5A
- Charge voltage: 19-24V
- 3S or 4S Li-ion pack
- Small board dimensions

Board is 2-layer, 70μm (2oz), 50x23mm (1968x906mil). On the Layout.jpg image I've shown battery, load and charger connection points.

[image: 3D rendering]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: PCB top layer]

[image: PCB bottom layer]

Dataheet: [BQ40Z60](http://www.ti.com/product/bq40z60)
Application notes: [sluua04c](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluua04c/sluua04c.pdf), [sluub71](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluub71/sluub71.pdf)

(schematics, layout and datasheets originally from here: https://yadi.sk/d/cAIporoBtRDc9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are mainly layout nits, nothing glaring. Note that the images are pretty hard to read.

- It would be better to arrange the traces that connect to SGND to arrive at the pad in a star topology rather than the ones that share the via at the intersection of UI1_16 and R12_1.

There are also some areas where you could use continuous copper pours to save etchant - just cover them with solder mask where they don't need to be exposed:

- The three large PGND pads on the right side of the top layer could be joined with a pour by moving the ADAPTER_ON trace to run up the middle between 1 PH and PGND. Then move the three vias in the empty space in the middle to make more room.
- Similarly you could have large SGND and PGND pours in the bottom left.

Finally, what about the mechanicals? It's a complete rectangle board with no cutouts, keepouts, or bosses and some components fairly near the edge. Must be nice. How is it going to be supported?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/OQ7B5SK8tUisA

Comment: Ok, tried to fix that. https://yadi.sk/i/OQ7B5SK8tUisA and https://yadi.sk/i/Am4xvwNttUisJ . At first I wasn't sure that it is possible to make a star with 2 layers and this amount of nets, but it turned out to be quite straight forward... About mounting: I'm planning to secure the board between 2 custom 18650 holders (with that rectangles on the sides).